# getting error class DetailCell has no initialisers

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DetailCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var articleNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var stock: UILabel!

    var post: AnyObject
        {

         didSet
            {
                self.configure()
        }

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
         self.articleNumber?.text = nil
        self.name?.text = nil
        self.stock?.text = nil
    }
    func configure()
    {

      self.articleNumber?.text = post.objectForKey("itemName") as? String
        self.name?.text = post.objectForKey("itemName") as? String
        self.stock?.text = post.objectForKey("stock")  as? String
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I am getting error message that class `DetailCell` has no initialisers.
I don't know why this is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `!` with `AnyObject` at `post` Instance declaration and final code will be:

```
var post: AnyObject! {

    didSet
    {
        self.configure()
    }

}
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)